# In the Google Analytics acquisition report, how is the percentage of users in each channel calculated?

Tags: google-analytics

The acquisition report shows a total number of users in the first column, broken down by channel. The number of users in each channel is followed by a percentage. This percentage does not reflect the actual percentage of (users in channel) / (total users). The percentage shown in consistently lower, suggesting a larger number of total users. I have seen this same discrepancy across all of my GA implementations, as well as in screenshots on the web of this report. What is this number a percentage of?

Strangely, the percentages shown for New Users and Sessions in the same report are equal to (new users or sessions in channel) / (total new users or sessions). I wondered if this had to do with how new vs. returning users are counted, but adding new and returning users in the Audience reports does not result in the same number.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I have answered this myself. The number of users in each channel adds up to a larger number than the total number of users because some users use multiple channels. The percentage given for each channel refers to the percentage of the total of all channels. New users and sessions are unique values and so are not repeated across channels. A user can only be counted as new once.